# How to use SQLite3 in combined Objective-C / Swift project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sqlite

I am working on an existing iOS 11+ app which has been developed over the last couple of years in Objective-C. New features are added using Swift.

Using Swift and Objectiv-C side by side has been no problem so far. However, now I am getting stuck while trying to use SQLite3 (which has been used within the Objectiv-C code for a long time) in Swift.

- The `libsqlite3.0.dylib` has been added to the targets *Link Binary With Libraries* section on the *Build Phase* tab a long time ago.
- Objective-C files using SQLite features simple use `#include <sqlite3.h>`. This works without any problem.
- A Bridging Header has also been setup properly a while a ago (otherwise it would not be possible to use any Objective-C code within the new Swift files)

Now I have added `#include <sqlite3.h>` to the Bridging Header file but this does not allow to use SQLite in Swift. For example the following error is shown:

```
func doSomething(withSQLResult result: sqlite3_stmt) {
    ...
}
```

> Use of undeclared type 'sqlite3_stmt'

---

I found different information on how to use SQLite3 in Swift. Some stated that special Swift version of SQLite is needed, others said that including `#include <sqlite3.h>` in the bridging header should work.

**So: How to use the existing SQLite setup which is used in Objective-C in Swift also?**

Comment: Even if this is directly doable it might make more sense for you to create Objective-C wrappers around the library and make them Swift-friendly. So you would for instance create `SQLResult` class which is constructed with instance of `sqlite3_stmt` and you add minimal needed functionality to it so you can work with it in Swift.

Comment: @MaticOblak This is an interesting approach which could indeed be a good solution for some classes (e.g. sqlite3_stmt). However, this is not only about `sqlite3_stmt` but many other classes / functions / features included in SQLite. This would be a lot of work...

Comment: Strange. I would say that next to DB initialization you would need a base class that has the capability to fetch items, insert, modify or delete items. Basically I would expect the interface to be like `MyDBObject.find(predicate, { items: [MyDBObject] in })` and `myDBObjectInstance.save( { success: Bool in } )`. A few more are needed in some cases but not many more. So in my opinion even `sqlite3_stmt` could possibly not be needed. I know it might be a bit late now to change the whole system but just for consideration.